# Overwrite the Rename action of Eclipse by my refactoring delegate

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin. I developed my refactoring process to rename the project name. I want to overwrite the existed action 'Rename' of Eclipse by my delegate action. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants` extension point to add a [rename participant](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ltk_core_refactoring_renameParticipants.html) to the existing participants. That way all plugins that need to do something when a project is renamed will still run correctly, and there are lots of plugins which need to run during a rename.

Comment: Hi, We have a plugin extension under org.eclipse.ui.handlers -> org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.renameResource (handler) that dates from 2015... This extension's class'es execute method is not called. But org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants extension points is called. At this point do I need execute via ExecutionEvent event parameter ? Because we have our own rename dialog box wizard ? In which we have our own label and text box ?

Comment: org.eclipse.ui.handlers -> org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.deleteResources (handler) which is also from 2015 executes properly.

Comment: @ilkeMuhtaroglu If you have a question please ask a new question, I will not respond to questions in comments

Comment: ok. I thought commenting is what you prefer. I ask immediately new question..